# get object initializer element name when building knockout viewmodel?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This may just require a general javascript answer instead of being knockout-specific but I'd like to know if there's a way to get the name of the particular element in the object initializer I'm creating below.

For example, I have an element called EmergentWorkConcerns that is getting initialized as an observable array through the create function and right now I am passing in a string value "EmergentWorkConcerns" to build the model. I found myself repeating this for a bunch of different types of arrays and I would like to minimize the use of magic strings if possible.

```
var ReportMapping = {
    EmergentWorkConcerns: {
        key: function (item) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.Id);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return rowEntryModel(options.data, "EmergentWorkConcerns", options.parent);
        }
    },
    SomeOtherRowType: {
        key: function (item) {
            return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.Id);
        },
        create: function (options) {
            return rowEntryModel(options.data, "SomeOtherRowType", options.parent);
        }
    },
    AnotherRowType: ...
};
```

So is there any way I can reference that EmergentWorkConcerns array from within my create function?

The only arguments exposed are 'options.parent' (the ReportMapping), 'options.data' (the specific Row) and 'options.skip'. Since we're in the global scope when calling the function, 'this' refers to the Window object.

Comment: What is `rowEntryModel` doing? Why does it need the name of the collection?

Comment: For example, I'm trying to find a way to get a reference to the collection so that I can expose something like an up arrow/down arrow in each row's view model to allow it to be moved up or down within that collection. $parent just gives me a reference to the ReportMapping itself but I need to go into the EmergentWorkConcerns collection to change the SortOrder value.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html):

> The **options** argument supplied to your **create** callback is a JavaScript object containing:
>
> - **data**: The JavaScript object containing the data for this child
> - **parent**: The parent object or array to which this child belongs

`options.parent` should give you the information you're looking for, itself being the array of `EmergentWorkConcerns`.

Comment: Unfortunately options.parent actually references the parent viewModel which only contains the EmergentWorkConcerns array as one member among all other things.